# Is this a Traveling salesman problem? If so, how to solve it?

Tags: minimum-spanning-tree, traveling-salesman

Given a group of cities and a starting city, we have to find a path that covers all the cities. The path doesn't need to end at the starting city. Is this a TSP problem? What is the solution for it?

This is not a homework problem or an interview question. I asked ChatGPT to find the shortest paths covering 5 random cities in my area and it told me that it is a TSP problem. I was thinking that this is more of a minimum spanning tree question. Can someone confirm this for me?

Comment: ChatGPT is Dunning-Kruger on steroids. Totally convinced and totally clueless.

Answer (score 0):

Take your TSP problem, then add a city X which has a distance of 0 from the starting city, and a T miles from any other city, where T is more than all other distances added.

If you solve the modified TSP instance, X must be one of the neighbours of the starting city, otherwise the tour would have a length of 2T. The distance of the shortest tour will be less than 2T, and exactly T longer than the optimal solution of the original problem. So you found the shortest tour that starts with the given start city and ends at another city. Compare this to the solution of the original problem, and you get the best tour that *may* end not at the starting city.

If no starting city is given, then add a city X that has the same long distance T from *each* city and solve the modified problem. The optimal tour for the modified problem is exactly 2T longer than the optimal tour that starts anywhere, and ends anywhere at another place.

Summary: To solve "May start anywhere, must end elsewhere" you add X with distance T from every other city, solve TSP, remove the two paths A -> X -> B, then take the route from B to A.

To solve "Must start at start city A, must end elsewhere" you add X with distance T from every other city except distance 0 from the start city, solve TSP starting at A, remove the two paths from some city to X.